# mkfifo Alternative

Tags: c++, c, unix

I have a process that continuously needs to write information. Furthermore, there is a second process which sometimes connects to the "information channel" of the writing process and should read the information that are written since it's connected. This process might also deconnect and reconnect several times again.

I am currently realizing this with a named pipe, by using mkfifo() in my c++ program. Unfortunately if I call open() on this fifo it blocks until a process opens the fifo for reading. This is quite normal for named pipes, but I need this open command to be non-blocking.

Do you know an alternative to mkfifo in this case?

Heinrich

Comment: I found mqueue.h which looks really interesting. Does someone know if this would be an appropriate solution?

Comment: You'll eventually have to either block or discard data, so which of those do you prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Unix-domain sockets, or regular TCP sockets on loopback interface.

Comment: Thats not a solution because my writer which is the server will have to wait for a client before sending and will be stuck in the accept() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared memory or mmap. It should contain offset to the oldest data, and the block of memory for data

fifo is limited to 64k (depends on distribution and some settings).

Answer (score 0):

I finally used the unix message queue, Reader and Writer can.be started totally independet and everything can be performed non blocking